# Manipular multiplus elementos por ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Minha questão é a seguinte: Eu estou customizando um File Input do bootstrap, e ao mesmo tempo transformando-o em plugin. A customização foi feita, mas o problema agora é fazer com que o botão de remoção do arquivo, não interfira em outros inputs do mesmo tipo, caso haja na tela. Com um input só, ele funciona muito bem, porém ao adicionar mais inputs, a validação do botão remover (caso não tenha arquivo selecionado ele não aparece, caso seja selecionado um arquivo ele aparece), só funciona para o primeiro input, no outro ele não pega.

Abaixo segue o código, estou fazendo um each para encontrar os IDs dos inputs e pegá-los para determinar em que input a ação está sendo efetuada, para que não haja interferência em outros inputs:

```js
function bs_input_file() {
            $(".input-file").find('input').each(function (index, dom) {
                var id = dom.id;
                $("#" + id).parent().find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");

                $(".input-file").before(
                    function () {
                        if (!$(this).prev().hasClass('input-ghost')) {
                            var element = $("<input type='file' id='" + id + "' class='input-ghost' style='visibility:hidden; height:0'>");
                            element.attr("name", $(this).attr("name"));
                            element.change(function () {
                                element.next(element).find('input').val((element.val()).split('\\').pop());
                            });
                            $(this).find("button.btn-choose").click(function () {
                                element.click();
                            });
                            $(this).find("button.btn-reset").click(function () {
                                element.val(null);
                                $(this).parents(".input-file").find('input').val('');
                                bs_input_file();
                            });
                            $(this).find('input').css("cursor", "pointer");
                            $(this).find('input').mousedown(function () {
                                $(this).parents('.input-file').prev().click();
                                return false;
                            });
                            console.log(element)
                            return element;
                        }
                    }
                );

                $("#" + id).change(function () {
                    var element = $("#" + id);
                    if (element.val() != "") {
                        $("#" + id).parent().find("button.btn-reset").removeClass("hidden");
                    } else {
                        $("#" + id).parent().find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");
                    }

                })

            })
        }

        bs_input_file();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h3>Example</h3>
    <form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <!-- COMPONENT START -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-file" name="Fichier1">
            <input id="fileInput0" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Select file...' />   
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-reset" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose " type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></em> Search...</button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-file" name="Fichier2">
            <input id="fileInput1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Select file...' />   
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-reset" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose " type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></em> Search...</button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- COMPONENT END -->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nessa parte: `$("<input type='file' id='" + id + "'...` você está criando elementos com o mesmo id do input text. Com isso dá problema mesmo porque um id deve ser único, ou seja, irá pegar sempre o primeiro.

Comment: Ele não deveria criar sistematicamente com o ID de referencia do elemento? Já que tudo está dentro de um each?

Comment: Olhe no "inspecionar elementos" e vc vai ver que o input text e o input file ficam com o mesmo id. Esse é o problema.

Comment: Então, mas isso é esperado mesmo porque o text e o file são referentes ao mesmo input, o text funciona como máscara, se você olhar o de baixo no outro form-group ele que é o problema, deveria ter outro ID

Comment: Eu entendi o propósito, mas os dois elementos não podem ter o mesmo id.

Comment: Entendi, como eu resolveria isso?

Comment: Ao meu ver teria que refazer o código, tô achando ele mt poluído.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = [];

  $(".input-file").find('input').each(function(index, dom) {
    id[index] = dom.id;

    $("#" + id[index]).parent().find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");

    $(".input-file").before(
      function() {
        if (!$(this).prev().hasClass('input-ghost')) {
          var element = $("<input type='file' id='" + id[index] + "' class='input-ghost inputfile' style='visibility:hidden; height:0'>");
          element.attr("name", $(this).attr("name"));
          element.change(function() {
            element.next(element).find('input').val((element.val()).split('\\').pop());
          });
          $(this).find("button.btn-choose").click(function() {
            element.click();
          });
          $(this).find("button.btn-reset").click(function() {
            element.val(null);
            $(this).parents(".input-file").find('input').val('');
            $(this).parents(".input-file").parent().find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");
          });
          $(this).find('input').css("cursor", "pointer");
          $(this).find('input').mousedown(function() {
            $(this).parents('.input-file').prev().click();
            return false;
          });
          console.log(element)
          return element;
        }
      }
    );
  })

  $(".inputfile").change(function() {
    i = $(".inputfile").index(this);

    if ($(".inputfile").eq(i).parent().find("button.btn-reset").hasClass("hidden")) {
      $(".inputfile").eq(i).parent().find("button.btn-reset").removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      $(".inputfile").eq(i).parent().find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <h3>Example</h3>
      <form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- COMPONENT START -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group input-file">
            <input id="fileInput0" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Select file...' />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-reset" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose " type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></em> Search...</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group input-file">
            <input id="fileInput1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Select file...' />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-reset" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose " type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></em> Search...</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- COMPONENT END -->
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```